# nodejs request module unable to request https url

Tags: node.js

i am trying to test Node module named REQUEST. I am in my office and behind proxy. What i have done is

```
const request = require('request');
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
const proxyReq=request.defaults ({'proxy': 'http:myoffproxy/IND'});

proxyReq.geturl(url,function(err,res,body)
```

It gives me error "Tunneling socket could not be estd. statusCode=400

If i use any http url it works fine and i could get response back. Seems something to deal with certifacate..
If i open https url given above it works fine in browser. Not sure how to fix this and why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried using https also for proxy?

Comment: Hi Barbsan, no what i have seen in my browser LAN settings and proxy address is http address only. How to do with https. Just saw this blog - 
   https://codingmiles.com/node-js-making-https-request-via-proxy/

Comment: hi i tried using first option in the given blog https://codingmiles.com/node-js-making-https-request-via-proxy/ so this time i get lot of metadata along with html body says Error 400. The request URL is in valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
request({url: sms}, function (error, response, body) { });
```

Comment: Hi King, already tried this as well but lands with same error. only error object is getting populated with same error what i have pasted ..others objects are undefined.